# How to reduce the number of TCP ACK's during a highly reliable bulk transfer

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, winsock, tcpclient

I've got an application where two computers are in very close distance - typically within a few feet of one another.

I've got a TCP connection between applications on the two computers. The server was written in C on Linux, the client on Windows using C# with TCPClient.

Over this socket I'm transferring very large payloads, often gigabytes at a time.

When I use Wireshark to monitor the communication I notice that about 66% of the *packets* transmitted are ACK's.  Each of the payload packets tends to be about 5k.  So the percentage of *data* in ACK's is very low,  just a percent or two.

Should I be concerned with the number of ACK's?   I'm not concerned with packet loss, I expect the connection to be of high quality in terms of packet loss.

Is there anything I can (or should?) do to reduce the number of ACK's?

Comment: How is that you are seeing packets that are 5KB in length? As that is well over the usual MTU size and TCP segment size?  I'm also assuming the ACKs are being sent in one direction (from the side receiving the data)?  Right?

Comment: @selbie - maybe it's not ethernet phy?  Perhaps it's some strange fiber link?

Answer (score 2):

What you're probably seeing is the receiver acknowledging the sender's transmissions. The receiver has to use ACK-only packets, as it doesn't have anything else to send (the sender also sends ACKs - every TCP packet contains an ACK).

I don't think you should be bothered by the number of ACKs - the sender isn't waiting for them if its window size is large enough. The question you should ask yourself is - am I getting the throughput I should be getting on my LAN speed?